# ImageButton crashes with "internal" OnClickListener

Tags: android, imagebutton, onclicklistener

For some reason, attaching an "internal" `OnClickListener` to an `ImageButton` crashes the app. For normal `Button`s it works fine - it's only the `ImageButton` that crashes it.

```
public class SomeWidgets extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ....
    button1         = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);   
    imagebutton     = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton)
    imagebutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    ....
    ....
}
```

The above code crashes when clicking the `imagebutton`. The `button1` works fine, even though both are created and attached to the `OnClickListener` in the exact same way. (It's the click that crashes it, and not the `onClick` handling of the click.)

However, if I create a private inner `OnClickListener` class and attach THAT one to the imagebutton, then it works fine.

Any ideas? Apparently, something goes wrong when attaching the "internal" `(this)` `OnClickListener` to an `ImageButton`, while it works fine when attaching it to a `Button`.

EDIT: Looks like I found the problem. If I override the onClick like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if (((Button)v).getText().equals("A button")) {
      edittext2.setText(edittext1.getText());
      edittext1.setText("");
   }
   if (imagebutton.getId() == R.id.imagebutton) {
      Toast.makeText(SomeWidgets.this, "This is an image button.",       
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

it crashes. However, if I remove the first if{} and only have the imagebutton if there, it works. This is obviously a silly error, but I'd appreciate and explanation as to why :-)

Comment: Show us the overridden `onClickListener` method, that is where the rror will be

Comment: I've updated the description. Please see if you can explain the silly noob error :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
if (((Button)v).getText().toString().equals("A button")) {
  edittext2.setText(edittext1.getText().toString());
  edittext1.setText("");
}
```

Comment: the EditText.getText() function return an Editable object, not a String.

Comment: Thanks, but Button != ImageButton. There's no getText() method for ImageButton (logically, since it doesn't contain any text).

Answer (score 0):

here change code

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.imagebutton) //imagebutton.getId() replace with View v
   {
      Toast.makeText(SomeWidgets.this, "This is an image button.",       
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

the crash is caused by the conversion from imageButton to Button, try:

```
if (v instanceOf ImageButton) {
   if (((ImagaeButton)v).getText().toString().equals("A button")) {
```

edit: 
if you add a OnClickListener to a Button and a ImageButon, you have to determine if the clicked object is the Button or ImageButton before you make a cast like (Button) v.
So you have to do something like:

```
String ButtonText = "";
if (v instanceOf ImageButton) {
   ButtonText = ((ImageButton) v).getText().toString();
}else if(v InstanceOf Button){
   ButtonText = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please update below code:-

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if (v==button1) {
      edittext2.setText(edittext1.getText());
      edittext1.setText("");
   } else if (v==imagebutton) {
      Toast.makeText(SomeWidgets.this, "This is an image button.",       
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone who answered. I don't see how I could've missed using toString(). Somehow I got caught up with the ImageButton and thought that was the problem. Fixing the text check for the Button in the onClick() fixed everything.